# pdfplumber - Extract table row splitted across multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, pdfplumber

Given a pdf(attached) with table row splitted across multiple pages with page break in between. I am trying to extract tabular data in a csv from this pdf using pdfplumber, but am getting this data in separate rows in a csv. Basically I would like to get this data in a single row.

With pdfplumber, is there a way to identify if the row has a horizontal border or not? If this information is available, it could help in merging the rows.

In the attached image, grey colour coded are the cells content.

[image]

Comment: There is no fail happening. Issue is just that, when I am extracting the tabular data in a csv, as both the page table are being considered as a different row, I am getting data in 2 separate rows instead they belong to a single row. With post processing, we can merge both the records and get a single record. But, I am interested in more generic solution which can handle other scenarios when the row isn't splitted across page.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the details. Is there a way to identify if the first part of the row in the first page has a bottom edge or not? and similarly top edge for the next part of the row in the next page ? If we could somehow identify that, it would also be an indicator that this belongs to a single row. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

pdfplumber objects have a `top` (distance of the top of the character from the top of the page). You can leverage it to know if the last page ends without a border and the first page starts without a border.

If the `top` value of the bottommost character is more than the `top` value of the bottommost horizontal line, then it means that the page is ending without the table border. Similarly, if the `top` of the topmost character is lower than the `top` of the topmost horizontal line, then it means that the page is starting without the table border. Combining the two, you can deduce whether to merge the rows or not.